# Is it possible in Ruby to redefine a initialize method?

Tags: ruby, open-closed-principle

I have a third-party code that's like this:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @hello = "world"
  end

  def msg
    @hello
  end
end
```

Then, I added a new file `foo_redefinition.rb` with these contents

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @hello = "welt"
  end
end
```

Then, another third party code calls a method in my main class, and in the file of my main class I do `require_relative 'foo_redefinition'`. However, when the third party code (after calling my method, thus reading my main file, which requires the redefinition) calls Foo.msg, it returns "world", not "welt".

Also, when I do

```
require_relative 'foo_redefinition'

# ... lots of code

Foo::new.msg #=> world (instead of welt)
```

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to redefine an initialize method?
2. If so, what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `initialize` is a method just like any other method. There is absolutely nothing special whatsoever about it. So, your question is: can I redefine methods? And the answer is: yes. The answer to your second question is: I don't know. There's not enough information in your post.

Comment: I assume thus I am redefining initialize after the instance I wished to alter (and to which I have no access whatsoever) has already been initialized, so the change occurs, but to no effect.

Comment: Answers to your questions are 1) yes;  2) I have no idea without seeing a full example which works the way you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that `Foo` is a lazily `autoload`ed class, and you are "redefining" `initialize` before `Foo` is loaded.

Try this

```
Foo.class_eval do
  def initialize
    @hello = "welt"
  end
end
```

This forces `Foo` to be loaded before redefining anything.